# Ionic/angularjs how to fix Cookie issue of unknown provider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, ionic-framework

I am trying to user cookies but I get the following error.

> ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   UserServiceProvider <- UserService <- AuthenticationService

I did the following:

1) mentioned this in my index.html

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

2) in my app.js I added ngCookies

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives','app.filters','ngSanitize','ngCookies','base64'])
```

3) then I created a new service, i referenced it in my index.

```
<script src="js/authenticationService.js"></script>
```

4) I included $cookies in my authenticationService.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('AuthenticationService', AuthenticationService);

    AuthenticationService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'UserService','$cookies'];
    function AuthenticationService($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout, UserService,$cookies) {...
```

can someone help me with the error?

When I change the angular cookies version to 1.2.20, i get this error instead

> ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: $browser.addPollFn is not a function
>       at Object. (angular-cookies.js:60)

Comment: The problem seems to be with UserService. Can you post the code for that ?

Comment: @m22an this is my very first time building an app and im 'learning as i go'. excuse my silly question but can you tell me what a UserService is? Did you mean the authentication.js file I created ?

Comment: In your authenticationService.js, you have this line `AuthenticationService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'UserService','$cookies'];`. This means that there should be injectable components like services / factories / controllers available for Angular when this service is initialized. In this case all components other than `UserService` are available either as a part of angular.js or as other packages like `angular-cookies.js`. Can you add a definition for UserService.js as well then your app should work.

Comment: @m22an yes, that worked! thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help, Please accept the answer, if it solved your problems. I also suggest you to do some reading about Angular in general as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above in the comments. In your authenticationService.js, you have this line `AuthenticationService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'UserService','$cookies'];`. This means that there should be injectable components like services / factories / controllers available for Angular when this service is initialized.

In this case all components other than `UserService` are available either as a part of `angular.js` or as other packages like `angular-cookies.js`.

Can you add a definition for `UserService.js` as well then your app should work.